# How to Create Different Steps in A Range Between two Numbers Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a dynamic range between two numbers with different given steps for example in `raneg1` 
the range is between `-9.00` to `+4.00` and it contains 3 different steps for

```
-9.00 -> -6.50 = step is 0.50
-6.00 -> 0.00 = step is 0.25
+0.25 -> +4.00 = step is is0.50
```

As you can see the data is stored in the `raneg1`  string like `-09.00_-6.50_0.50` as `beginingof subrange_end of subrange_step`

```js
var rane1 = " -09.00_-6.50_0.50,-6.00_0.00_0.25,+0.25_+4.00_0.50";
var rane2 = " -04.00_-9.25_0.25,-09.00_-6.50_0.50,-6.00_0.00_0.25,+0.25_+8.00_0.50";

var ranearr1 = rane1.split(/\,\s*/).reduce(function(arr, item) {
  if (item.length) {
    arr.push(item.split('_'));
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

var ranearr2 = rane2.split(/\,\s*/).reduce(function(arr, item) {
  if (item.length) {
    arr.push(item.split('_'));
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

var list = [];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the A_B_steps pattern, is A always less than B?

Comment: Hi Colin, yes it is

Comment: And for different steps, in your example, you have 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, should it be 2 different steps instead of 3?

Comment: they are not fixed! sometimes even diffrent number

Comment: Yes, I mean, how you count different steps? You said 0.5, 0.25, and 0.5 are 3 different step, but should it be only 2 since there are two 0.5

Comment: well, lets say the 3 step is dfiirent and it is 1

Comment: What is your expected output for `rane1`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the step part.

First approach finds how many unique step in ranges.

Second approach will check number of steps needs for each range in ranges string, and only counts unique number of steps.

```js
var rane1 = " -09.00_-6.50_0.50,-6.00_0.00_0.25,+0.25_+4.00_0.50";
var rane2 = " -04.00_-9.25_0.25,-09.00_-6.50_0.50,-6.00_0.00_0.25,+0.25_+8.00_0.50";

const dynamicRange = (ranges) => {
  //set to count different step
  const counter = new Set();
  //reduce to count min max value for each range
  const minMax = ranges.split(/\,\s*/).reduce((res, range) => {
    const [start, end, step] = range.split('_');
    counter.add(step)
    return [
      res[0]&&parseFloat(res[0])<parseFloat(start) ? res[0] : start,
      res[1]&&parseFloat(res[1])>parseFloat(end) ? res[1] : end,
    ]
  
  }, [])
  //return [start, end, different step]
  return [...minMax, counter.size]
}


//count different steps need for each range
const dynamicRangeDiffSteps = (ranges) => {
  //set to count unique number of steps needs for each range
  const counter = new Set();
  //reduce to count min max value for each range
  const minMax = ranges.split(/\,\s*/).reduce((res, range) => {
    const [start, end, step] = range.split('_');
    //convert start, end step to float
    const sFloat = parseFloat(start), eFloat = parseFloat(end), stepFloat = parseFloat(step)
    //add number of steps needed to set
    counter.add((eFloat-sFloat)/stepFloat)
    return [
      res[0]&&parseFloat(res[0])<sFloat ? res[0] : start,
      res[1]&&parseFloat(res[1])>eFloat ? res[1] : end,
    ]
  
  }, [])
  //return [start, end, different step]
  return [...minMax, counter.size]
}

console.log(dynamicRange(rane1))
console.log(dynamicRange(rane2))

console.log(dynamicRangeDiffSteps(rane1))
console.log(dynamicRangeDiffSteps(rane2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```